# How can I elegantly create a hash from an array reference in Perl?

Tags: perl, arrays, hash, reference

I am looking for a more elegant way to create a hash that contains the list I have read in from my configuration file.  Here is my code:

```
read_config($config_file => my %config);

my $extension_list_reference = $config{extensions}{ext};

my @ext;

# Store each item of the list into an array

for my $i ( 0 .. (@$extension_list_reference - 1) ) {
    $ext[$i] = $extension_list_reference->[$i];
}

# Create hash with the array elements as the keys

foreach my $entry (@ext) {
    $extensions{$entry} = "include";
 }
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm going to give you the benefit of the doubt and assume you just forgot to include the "use strict;" and "use warnings;" that are surely at the top of your code.

Comment: One of the most frustrating things I found about Perl when I first learned it is that strict wasn't on by default. I'll throw them in for completeness.

Comment: Oh wait, this isn't my question. It's some other Neil's question. oops!

Comment: We should do something so all us "Neil"s don't get confused!  Can be update our names?  May I suggest you become "Brooklyn Neil" and I'll become "D.C. Neil".

Answer (score 13):

`my %hash = map { $_ => 'include' } @list;`

Comment: The following worked:   %extensions = map {$_  => "include" } @$extension_list_reference;

Answer (score 6):

Try using map:
http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html

Here's what your new code should look like:

```
my %extensions = map { $_ => "include" } @{ $config{extensions}{ext} };
```

Comment: Thanks.  How's Brooklyn?  My birthplace.

Comment: It's nice, just moved here 4 months ago.

Comment: my %extensions = map { $_ => "include" } @{ $config{extensions}{ext} }

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem, this is how you do it in one line:

```
@extensions{@$extension_list_reference} = ();
```

Note: each value of the hash is empty, but you still can check whether the key exists in the hash using function **exists**, like this:

```
if(exists $extensions{$some_key}) {...
```

P.S. If by some reason you really need those strings 'include' as values, you can have them, too:

```
@extensions{@$extension_list_reference} = ('include') x @$extension_list_reference;
```

Comment: Why does this work instead of :  %extensions{@$extension_list_reference} = (); ?

Comment: Because you are operating on a 'hash slice': http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices

Comment: This works fine when the list has more than one value.  It's possible that someone could have only one value in their configuration file.  How could I handle one value versus many values?

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to include the error message I get if the list contains only one item:  Can't use string (".frames") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at
        create_video_frames.pl line 209 (#1)
    (F) Only hard references are allowed by "strict refs".  Symbolic
    references are disallowed.  See perlref.

Uncaught exception from user code:
        Can't use string (".frames") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at create_video_frames.pl line 209.
 at create_video_frames.pl line 209

Comment: You can check what $extension_list_reference points by using the ref function. So $extension_list_reference = ref $extension_list_reference ? $extension_list_reference : [ $extension_list_reference ]; ought to do it.

Comment: Neil, it looks like the problem is in read_config function, and that it works differently when you have just one item - it returns a string instead of a reference. If you don't have access to read_config, you can use the abovementioned trick from Sinan Unur comment.

Comment: There are three cases to deal with:  one item, more than one items and zero items.  Could someone explain this statement:  $extension_list_reference = ref $extension_list_reference ? $extension_list_reference : [ $extension_list_reference ]; 

ref $extension_list_reference will return something like "array",  "string" or "undef"?

Comment: Neil, if read_config() treats all 3 cases consistently, you don't need to worry about ref. It's just a (quick and dirty) workaround; but it's better to fix the problem than create a workaround. Please take a look at your read_config(), at the place where you populate %config hash. The problem should be there.

Comment: @raindog I think Neil is using http://search.cpan.org/~dconway/Config-Std-v0.0.4/lib/Config/Std.pm#Multi-part_configuration_values which only returns a list of values if the key appears more than once.

Comment: Ouch. Sinan, you're right.
Neil, disregard my question, just do what Sinan has proposed. Note: you'll need this workaround with every solution, it has nothing to do with slicing.

Comment: I am using Config-Std-v0.0.4.  I would like to understand Sinan's workaround.  What's the difference between:   

"$extension_list_reference" and "[ $extension_list_reference ]" ?

Comment: The operator [] creates a reference to an array. 

The function read_config() can create either a reference to an array, or just a string. If this is a reference, you don't need to do anything. If this is a string, [ "something" ] will create an array and return a reference to it.

Answer (score 1):

This way:

```
read_config($config_file => my %config);
%extensions = map +($_ => "include"), @{$config{extensions}{ext}};
```

or this way:

```
read_config($config_file => my %config);
@extensions{@{$config{extensions}{ext}}} = ("include") x @{$config{extensions}{ext}};
```

Comment: I like this approach - Thanks.